# Modular Nodejs application Set

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, node-modules

I want to create a modular node.js application stack containing a set of applications. The idea is that app1, app2, etc can use the controllers and models.

Inside each app folder, I can have app specific package.json, app.js, etc.
I am using express.

I have two issues:

1. Is it possible to have that structure?
2. Why I'm not able to deploy such an app set on GCP? When I try It throws `500 internal server error`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7DN9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To create a similar architecture, even if I didn't find a way to have the same, you should use `services`. According to the [official GAE doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#services):

> Use services in App Engine to factor your large apps into logical
>   components that can securely share App Engine features and communicate
>   with one another. Generally, your App Engine services behave like
>   microservices. Therefore, you can run your whole app in a single
>   service or you can design and deploy multiple services to run as a set
>   of [microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine).

Does this work for your use case?

Regarding question 2, you didn't provide any information about your current process, so I cannot help you. Please edit the question adding the deployment configuration (app.yaml, etc.) and how is it performed. Please delete any sensitive information before posting it.